# Sumar todas las llaves con el nombre val

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

quisiera saber como puedo hacer que se sumen todas las llaves que contengan el nombre "val"

```
    var data = [
      {val: 5, name: "one"},
      {val: 8, name: "two'}
   ]

//Resultado esperado [13]
```

pero no puedo usar "for()" porque ya esta dentro de uno, y hace que tarde demasiado en cargar, quiero saber si hay mas maneras

Comment: Puedes sumarlos data[0].val + data[1].val

Comment: Aunque no se vea óptimo anidar un for dentro de otro, si es la única forma de resolver el problema hacerlo de otra forma no será más rápido. Las funciones de arreglos como `map, reduce` aunque son cortas de escribir internamente tienen que iterar el arreglo. Cuando se trabaja en programas donde el tiempo de ejecución es prioridad  las estructuras más simples como while y for tienen mejor rendimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la función [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) sobre el array `data`.

```
var data = [
  {val: 5, name: "one"},
  {val: 8, name: "two"}
];

function reducer(acumulador, item){
    return acumulador+item.val;
}

console.log(data.reduce( reducer, 0 ));
```